# Using textOutput in showModal

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add a textOutput to my modalDialog and it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated. I realize this isn't a working example but the app is insanely massive and I'm running out of time to create a mini example. I'm also fairly inexperienced with modalDialog.
Everything works as planned except the textOutput - it simply doesn't show.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(DT)
library(digest)
library(DBI)
library(shinyjs)
library(highcharter)
library(pool) #devtools::install_github("rstudio/pool")
library(shinyFeedback)
library(summaryrow)

showModal(
 modalDialog(
  fluidRow(
   column(
    width = 3,
    h1("Expense"),
    numericInput(
      inputId = ns("payment_expense_a"),
      label = "Expense Payment by A",
      value = 0
    ),
    numericInput(
      inputId = ns("payment_expense_b"),
      label = "Expense Payment by B",
      value = 0
    ),
    h4(
      textOutput("attorney_paid_total") #This is sum of A and B payments
    )
   )
   ...
  )
 )
)
...
output$attorney_paid_total <- renderText({    
  paste0("Total Attorney Paid: XXX") #This will be reactive
})
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please include relevant libraries that you use at the top. I have no idea what `ns()` function is

Comment: @KyleWeise
`ns <- session$ns`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) I just had to wrap it in ns()

`h4(textOutput(ns("attorney_paid_total")))`

Comment: Please provide a working example. Just wrapping by `ns()` is not sufficient, `ns()` is not even function exported from the shiny package.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `output$expense_paid_total` and not `output$attorney_paid_total` as a `textOutput` id.

You do not have in the code which you provided any `textOutput` with `id = attorney_paid_total`. Therefore i assume the problem is with the incorrect id of the `textOutput`, and it should like:

```
...
output$expense_paid_total <- renderText({    
  paste0("Total Attorney Paid: XXX") #This will be reactive
})
...
```

Please next time provide [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), without it noone can really help in your problem, just assume something...

Comment: I just typed it wrong when I added the code. I edited my question to reflect my typo fix. I also realize I need a working example but like I said in my question, I am a newbi with modal (I didn't write the app, just editing it) and I don't have time to create one. But thank you for pointing our the error,